# Retain Dynamically Added DOM Elements when logging out

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I recently came across a feature that Salesforce Applications have, i.e. when we log out, the tabs opened during the session are preserved and are displayed again when we log back in at a later point of time.
I would like to implement something similar in my web application where I would like to retain the dynamically created DOM elements so that if I refresh the page or logout, those elements still are displayed unless the end user decides to delete/close/destroy those elements.

Has anyone implemented anything that sounds familiar? If yes, what would be the ideal way to go about it?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a webapplication that holds users and adresses as well as various different values. I have implemented a review function as a helper if you go through your data on an infrequent basis. It marks each value as reviewed or not. As this feature is only a helper and a review flag or timestamp is not needed and implemented in the DB, I save an array of data as a JSON string locally using localstorage.
This is enough for my case. You could do the same for your datamodell. You can of course also save this data per user on a separate table in the db. Consider something like: id, userid, featurename, etc.. with this generic layout you can save the state for each feature of your app, be it a tab, a modal, a setting or whatever.

Of course, you need a (preferably JS) function that gets these settings and then can recreate the DOM elements or fetch them via AJAX. You need as well a function that sends an AJAX request to save the information that a feature/window/tab has been opened/closed/etc.

A lot of work for a "nice feature". Might not be a top priority on your bucketlist, but definitly enhances your user experience.

Comment: I guess the only way to retain the dynamic information would be with the help of a back end service. The use of localstorage alone, sounds easy to implement, however the scope would be limited to one session/browser without a DB.

Comment: Thats true. There is no way around the server db if you want that information accesible everywhere. As I said, its a lot of work for a nice feature. I would implement it once you have implemented the realy important stuff stable.

Answer (score 0):

> I refresh the page or logout, those elements still are displayed
>   unless the end user decides to delete/close/destroy those elements.

That can only be possible if before `refresh/logout` those dynamically created elements are stored.

That can be possible by either storing the value in database or using `local/session` storage.

Values of the dynamically generated elements can be stored in localStorage like

```
localStorage.set('someKeyName' ,'value of dynamically generated Elements in string format')
```

Then after refresh retrieve the values and create those elements and append it to dom